# Finding the minimum number which when added to running sum of array is 1

Tags: algorithm, math

Starting with a given array of integers and a value 'x'. Calculate the running sum of x plus each array element, from left to right. The running sum must never get below 1.  Determine the minimum value of x.

For eg. arr = [-2, 3, 1, -5].

If x = 4, the following results are obtained:

```
Running     
sum       arr[i]
-----     -----
4          -2
2           3
5           1
6          -5
1
```

Any ideas how to find this. I tried starting from '0' and slowly incrementing until we reach 1, but thats a wrong approach, I guess.

Comment: stop cheating on your coding challenges :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perform the accumulation in reverse, meaning:

Start with 1 and *subtract* values from the *end* of the array walking back to the the start of the array. Whenever you get a value that is less than 1, correct it to 1 before continuing the subtractions.

The value you get at completion of this algorithm is the minimum value of *x* you are looking for.

Implementation in a runnable JavaScript snippet:

```js
function getMinX(arr) {
    let x = 1;
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        x = x - arr[i];
        if (x < 1) x = 1;
    }
    return x;
}

let arr = [-2, 3, 1, -5];
console.log(getMinX(arr)); // 4
```

Some languages support *functional programming* style, in which you can use a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). In JavaScript that would be coded as:

```js
const getMinX = arr => arr.reduceRight((x, val) => Math.max(1, x-val), 1);

console.log(getMinX([-2, 3, 1, -5])); // 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You should

1. Calculate rolling sums for the input array of integers (time O(n))
   E.g.: `arr =  [-2, 3, 1, -5]` => `arr_rolling =  [0, -2, 1, 2, -3]`
2. Get the minimum element among the sums -- `min_sum` (time O(n))
   E.g.: `arr_rolling =  [0, -2, 1, 2, -3]` => `min_sum = -3`
3. `X = 1 - min_sum` (time O(1))
   E.g.: `min_sum = -3` => `X = 4`

The final time complexity is O(n).

Once you understand the algorithm, you may notice that there's no need to store rolling sums and you can calculate rolling sum minimum "on the fly". Once you notice it, the memory usage becomes O(1).

Comment: Hi, can you explain why your algorithm works? on a table test I've seen that works, but I couldn't get it why

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira, sure. 
How does the prepending of an element X affects the rolling sums of the array? All of them increase by X. Essentially, you need to know "how small the rolling sum can get while I move from the first element to the last". When you know it, you know what value is enough to prepend to the array to "lift up" this minimum to the smallest satisfying value (1 in our case). Say, minimum rolling sum is -5, then you need to "lift up" rolling sums by 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the array left-to-right adjusting for x as you go (Python):

```
In [2]: arr = [-2, 3, 1, -5]

In [3]: accum = x = 0

In [4]: for item in arr:
   ...:     accum += item
   ...:     if accum < 1:
   ...:         x += 1 - accum
   ...:         accum = 1
   ...:         

In [5]: accum
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: x
Out[6]: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def minX(arr):
    temp,count1,counter,found= 1,2,len(arr)-1,False
    while  counter !=-1 :
        temp+=(arr[counter] * -1)
        counter -=1
        if temp < 1 :
            temp = 0
            temp += count1
            count1 += 1
            counter = len(arr)-1
    return temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/******************************************************************************

Welcome to GDB Online.
GDB online is an online compiler and debugger tool for C, C++, Python, Java, PHP, Ruby, Perl,
C#, VB, Swift, Pascal, Fortran, Haskell, Objective-C, Assembly, HTML, CSS, JS, SQLite, Prolog.
Code, Compile, Run and Debug online from anywhere in world.

*******************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int minX(vector<int> &arr)
{
    vector<int> temp;
    int sumwX = 1;
    for(auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it)
    {
        sumwX += *it;
        temp.push_back(sumwX);
    }
    
    return (1 - (*min_element(temp.begin(), temp.end()) - 1 ));
}

int main()
{
    
    vector<int> M = {-5,4,-2,3,29,-1,-6,-1,0,-5};
    vector<int> N = {-2,3,1,-5};
    vector<int> V = {-5,4,-2,3,1,-1,-6,-1,0,-5};
    cout << minX(M) << endl;
    cout << minX(N) << endl;
    cout << minX(V) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```